# Invalid int errors in Android

Tags: android, int, fatal-error

I'm trying my hand at android app creation and thought a dice tool for a tabletop game would be a nice project. However I keep getting invalid int errors on line 40 and I'm pretty stumped as to what I've actually done wrong.

If anyone could point me in the right direction with this I'd really appreciate it :)

```
package com.example.isaac.dicetool;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText et1,et2;
    TextView Result;
    Button button;
    ToggleButton toggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        toggle=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
            int min = 1;
            int max = 6;
            int rolls = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
            int win = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
            Random r = new Random();
            int sucess = 0;
            int explode = 0;
            boolean exp =((ToggleButton)arg0).isChecked();

                for(int i=0;i<rolls;i++){
                    int roll = r.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
                if(roll<win){
                        sucess++;
                    }
                if(exp==true){
                    if(roll==6){
                        rolls++;
                        explode++;
                    }
                }
                }
                Result.setText("Number of successes: " + sucess + "n/Number of explosions: " + explode);
           }
                                  }

        );


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Number of Dice(D6)"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Number for Success"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:numeric="integer" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ROLL!"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" />

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToggleButton"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textOff="Normal"
    android:textOn="Exploding" />
```

```
05-20 13:04:15.830    1866-1866/com.example.isaac.dicetool E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.isaac.dicetool, PID: 1866
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
        at com.example.isaac.dicetool.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which line is line 40?

Comment: Hello @Zaku212, can you please provide us with the stack trace and the  activity_main.xml?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to convert probably an empty string "" value into an `integer`!

```
   int rolls = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
```

if your `EditText` `edt1` doesn´t have value you will have a `NumberFormatException` here.

the same with the next line of code:

```
  int win = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
```

You can validate with:

```
et1Val = et1.getText().toString();
if (et1Val.matches("")) {
    et1Val = "0";
}
int rolls = Integer.parseInt(et1Val);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply on this, but the issue still happens when the editText is given an int vaule from a number field on the gui. I understand that it needs this to assign zero should the field be left empty.